# Autohotkey regex exclude part of string

Tags: regex, string, autohotkey

Using Autohotkey, I need to exclude a part of a string, while still writing the first and last part of it.
I'll explain. Given the String:

> GSM NWS\TOP N Pool 1\1. TOP N Pool 1 Rank :
>
> GSM NWS\TOP N Pool 1\1. TOP N Pool 1 BCCH :
>
> GSM NWS\TOP N Pool 1\1. TOP N Pool 1 BSIC :

I Need to extract only the parts from "`1.`" until "`:`", excluding the "`TOP N Pool 1`" part. Thus, the wanted string should be:

1. Rank
2. BCCH
3. BSIC

I've been around this question for quite a while now, and I've used RegExMatch:

```
RegExMatch(A_LoopField,  "\d+\.(.*?)\[\d\]", fields%lineCount%)
```

This RegEx is not excluding that middle string I want to leave out.

Any ideas?

P.S: I'm relatively new to this language, and to the Regular Expression usage as well...please forgive if i'm making any basic mistake here.

Thank you all.

Comment: There are many ways to match the data you need. You have to be specific on what is variable, what is fixed, optional (etc..), the type of text you want to grab, Otherwise it's a guessing game ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use capturing groups, like in regex:

```
(\d\.).+\d\s(\w+)\s:
```

parts in parentheses capture text, which you can use afterward, using `$1`,`$2`, etc. Here `$1` is for `(\d\.)` which captures for example: `1.` , and `$2` for `(\w+)` which should capture `Rank`. So I suppose (as I don't have a background in AHK) you should be able to do something like:

```
NewStr := RegExReplace("GSM NWS\TOP N Pool 1\1. TOP N Pool 1 Rank :", "(\d\.).+\d\s(\w+)\s:", "$1$2")
```

and the result should be: `1.Rank`

Look here how regex works: [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/qW7vV3/2)

Comment: Hi, the solution that you provided has some sense, but the result is a bit different than expected. While isolating those two groups, when we replace the text with those two sub-strings, the original string is maintained. In short: the same string we pass as "Haystack" to the RegExReplace command is the final result of the command. Is there any way to present only $1 and $2, excluding the rest of the string? Thank you.

Comment: @Bruno try with `.+(\d\.).+\d\s(\w+)\s:` I give me feedback :)